# Run Python script in Command prompt

Tags: python, c#, cmd

I need to run a Python script from my C# program and see the result. But my below code isn't working, the working directory changes but it doesn't seem like Arguments part is run.
The commented line (writeline) is me trying to send commands after opening cmd because sending them as arguments didn't work. That is giving an error (Message  "StandardIn has not been redirected.) and Googling gave me that UseShellExecute needs to be false but that didn't work.

Attached image shows how command prompt opens.

```
private void run_cmd(string pathPythonExe, string pathPyFolder, string SN)
        {

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = pathPyFolder;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = pathPythonExe + " Z19003.py --sn " + SN;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.Start();
            //p.StandardInput.WriteLine(pathPythonExe + " Z19003.py --sn " + SN);
```

I've tried different ways to open cmd and run that I found online but nothing seems to work.
Running the Python script works if I just copy-paste the command to command prompt. But I want to automate that part.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? And do you really need to open a cmd first? Otherwise you might want to try `FileName = pathPythonExe` and remove it from the `Arguments`.

Comment: "cmd" cannot "execute" python... You should use "python" as executable ... You can allow windows/system to choose what opens *.py but hen you should use UseShellExecute=true

Comment: It seems I knew even less on the subject than I thought. Running python.exe instead of cmd works. The reason I arrived at the code I had is because samples that ran python.exe didn't work for me. Can't remember anymore what was different there. But now it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Firstly, let's break the semantics of a process. A process is a program which is currently running and its operation status is kept under observation by the OS by using multiple monitoring techniques. Now the question is how a process can communicate with other programs, and the OS itself, and vice-versa? The answer lies in one fundamental characteristic of every ***OS*** kernel, and that is the ***STDIN***, ***STOUT***, and ***STDERR*** Input / Output ( ***I/O*** ) streams. The ***STDIN*** stream is responsible for processing input related data, the ***STDOUT*** is responsible for processing output related data, and the ***STDERR*** stream is responsible for processing error messages related data. These streams are used by processes and the ***OS*** itself to process input, process output, and process errors, and these streams are necessary for the processes to process all the ***I/O*** information.

```
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = pathPyFolder;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = pathPythonExe + " Z19003.py --sn " + SN;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.Start();
```

In the code shown above, the output given by the ***Python*** script cannot be seen because the input given by the script is sent through the ***OS*** itself and not to the ***C#*** application, because the ***STDOUT*** script was not redirected to go through the ***C#*** application.

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

The line shown above means that the ***Python*** script will be started by the ***C#*** application, not the ***OS*** shell, which is necessary when redirecting the ***STDOUT*** stream. To redirect the ***STDOUT*** stream, the propriety of the ***Process*** class named  `RedirectStandardOutput` must be set to true, `p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;`. To run the ***Python*** script, you need to run the ***Python*** interpreter and pass the name of the script file as an argument to be run. To run the ***Python*** interpreter you either call the `python` command or run the ***Python*** interpreter executable by calling it through its path (e.g.`C:\Users\John\...\Python 3.10\python.exe`). To start the ***Python*** interpreter, you must set either the path to the ***Python*** interpreter or the ***Python*** command as the value of the `FileName` propriety of the `Process` class, and this is shown below.

```
// WHEN USING PATHS PUT THE PATH BETWEEN (") IN ORDER 
// TO FORMAT WHITE SPACES AND TREAT THEM AS STRINGS

p.StartInfo.FileName = "python"; //Python command

                                 // OR

                                 // Path to Python interpreter
p.StartInfo.FileName = "\"C:\\Users\\John\\...\\Python 3.10\\python.exe\"";
```

To run the desired script, it must be passed as an argument to the interpreter by setting the `Arguments` propriety of the ***Process*** class as the path to the Python script `p.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\Users\\John\\script.py";`. The resulting code that starts the ***Python*** interpreter, runs the script, and sets the ***STDOUT*** stream to be redirected through the ***C#*** application is shown below.

```
// WHEN USING PATHS PUT THE PATH BETWEEN (") IN ORDER 
// TO FORMAT WHITE SPACES AND TREAT THEM AS STRINGS

using System.Diagnostics;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"C:\\Users\\John\\script.py\""
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();
```

To read the ***STDOUT*** stream sent by the application, the `ReadLine()` method of the ***Process*** class must be called.

## Final code

### C# code

```
// WHEN USING PATHS PUT THE PATH BETWEEN (") IN ORDER 
// TO FORMAT WHITE SPACES AND TREAT THEM AS STRINGS

using System.Diagnostics;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"C:\\Users\\John\\script.py\""
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();

Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
```

### Python code

```
print("!!! Message from Python script !!!")
```

## Result

[image]